# PowerShell treats a property that only overrides its setter as write-only

Tags: powershell

I have a C# class (`B`) that inherits a property (`p2`) with a getter and a setter, but only overrides the setter. The problem is that I can't read that property using PowerShell.

**Is this a bug in PowerShell? Is there a simple way to read the `p2` property of `$b` directly from PowerShell?**

This is my sample PowerShell:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    public class A {
        public virtual string p1{get;set;}

        public virtual string p2{
            get{return "Agetp2-"+p1;}
            set{p1 = "Asetp2-"+value;}
        }
    }
    public class B : A {
        public override string p2{
            set{p1 = "Bsetp2-"+value;}      
        }
    }
    public class Test {
        public static string getP2(){
            B b = new B();
            b.p2 = "TEST";
            return b.p2;
        }
    }
"@
```

If I try to get the `p2` propert of `B` using powershell:

```
$b = New-Object B
$b.p2 = "TEST"
$b.p2
```

I get an error:

> ```
> Cannot get property value because "p2" is a write-only property.
>
> at line: 1 Character: 1
> + $b.p2
> + ~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WriteOnlyProperty
> ```

However, if I run the C# test method:

```
[Test]::getP2()
```

I get the expected output:

> ```
> Agetp2-Bsetp2-TEST
> ```

This is my `$PSVersionTable`:

> ```
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> PSVersion                      5.1.16299.251
> PSEdition                      Desktop
> PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
> BuildVersion                   10.0.16299.251
> CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
> WSManStackVersion              3.0
> PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
> SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
> ```

Comment: Yes, it looks like a possible bug. Using `$b | Get-Member` verifies that the property is implemented with only a setter. However, if you compile the code to an ConsoleApp using `Add-Type`, the console app will work as expected. I recommend reporting it on https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell